# Serving static files in IISNODE with StaticFiles URL Rewrite

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I am trying to deploy a Node.js application on IIS. I saw the samples on the GitHub repository (https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/tree/master/src/samples).

I am stuck at serving static files. Like a normal Node application, I stored the static files in a folder named public. As per suggestions on several blogs/forums I added the following rule to web.config:

```
<rule name="StaticContent">
  <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
</rule>
```

But it doesn't work. If anyone has a sample application demonstrating this issue, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out a sample iisnode web.config that redirects requests for static files in the `public` folder to the IIS's static file handler instead of Node.js at http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/05/yaml-configuration-support-in-iisnode.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should be format of the relative path to be specified while referring to the script file in an HTML file after applying the rewrite?

Comment: The same as if the web.config was completely absent and default IIS rules applied (including not recognizing your server.js as a Node.js application). The static content rule does not rewrite the URL, it just prevents the iisnode handler from intercepting it.

Comment: Just confirming, so relative path of a static JavaScript file would be /appname/public/scripts/main.js. Correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Just a quick note: {{REQUEST_URI}}  didn't work for me, but {REQUEST_URI} worked just file.
I've also changed "Static rule" to match static file, not to check if it's physical file in dynamic. So it looks pretty much as typical nginx config: <match url="\.(?:jpg|jpeg|css|png|js|ico|html)$" /> and rewrite

Comment: @DmitriSosnik do you have an example?

Comment: @JoshC. Sure, this one works for me - [https://gist.github.com/dimavs/ab540cc78b689c2727aa](https://gist.github.com/dimavs/ab540cc78b689c2727aa)

Comment: Anyone mind answering why is it necessary to redirect requests to IIS's static file handler? Why can't I just use the Node/Express to serve static files?

Comment: @TheCrazyProgrammer "Using IIS static file handler has a large performance benefit compared to serving static content from within a node.js application. The handler leverages IIS and OS low level caching mechanisms which offer superb performance." I haven't run any tests but guess it makes sense.

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone comes across this question on Google and had problems with the sample web.config mentioned in the accepted answer...

This is the web.config file that worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<configuration>  
    <system.webServer>           
        <handlers>  
            <add name="iisnode" path="server/app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />  
        </handlers>  
        <rewrite>  
            <rules>  
                 <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">  
                      <match url="iisnode" />  
                 </rule>  
                 <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                      
                    <match url="^server\/app.js\/debug[\/]?" />  
                 </rule>  
                <rule name="StaticContent" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{C:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*?virtualpath\/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
                    <rule name="DynamicContent" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{{REQUEST_FILENAME}}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server/app.js" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>  
       </rewrite>  

        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <add segment="node_modules" />
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security> 
    </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

My folder structure is:

- virtualpath/ - refers to the IIS configured Virtual Path

  - public/ - contains static content
  - server/ - contains server application files

Comment: Almost 3 years later... but how do I find my virtualpath in IIS?

Comment: The virtual path is the name of your web application in IIS

Comment: @MarkT virtual path in azurewebsites would be 'wwwroot'?

Comment: @MarkT https://i.imgur.com/2P8Fx5P.png Error 405 the POST method not allowed. I'm hopeless =/

Comment: Works great. In case anyone also finds this via search... your static files may be in another folder called `assets` within the `public` folder. So you just do this `<rule name="StaticContent" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/assets/{C:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*?assets\/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>`
A URL with assets in will be served by IIS